# Azure B2C custom policy - api.localaccountsignup - only some fields are automatically translated

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have used the B2C starterpack as the basis of my new policy.

Almost everything works after some epic battles but the translation seems to be somehow only partially done.
I dont believe that Microsoft really left out just those couple of strings so there must be some error on my side..

I have also tried to do the translation by hand - but i cannot find the Ids to translate for

Email Address

New Password

Confirm New Password

These strings are not mentioned at all in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids

How is it possible that the buttons for Continue and Cancel ***are*** translated, but those fields are not ?

After all this comes directly from B2C in the `<div id='api'>` tag, so its kind of strange that i need to do the translations manually for those base fields.

```
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
          <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
            <!-- <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item> Had to disable this to get the translation -->
          </Metadata>
```

```
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignup">                 
        <LoadUri>https://my_blob_on.core.windows.net/b2c/custom-ui.html</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:1.2.0</DataUri>
        <!-- <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:selfasserted:1.1.0</DataUri> - No Changes with this -->
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Local account sign up page</Item>
        </Metadata>
        <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" 
 LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.localaccountsignup.en" />
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="de" 
 LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.localaccountsignup.de" />
        </LocalizedResourcesReferences></ContentDefinition>
```

```
    <Localization Enabled="true">
      <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en" MergeBehavior="Prepend">
        <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
        <SupportedLanguage>de</SupportedLanguage>
        <SupportedLanguage>it</SupportedLanguage>
      </SupportedLanguages>
<!-- adding my DIY translations as B2C doesnt provide them ?! -->
      <LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccountsignup.en">
        <LocalizedStrings>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="givenName" StringId="DisplayName">Given Name</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="surname" StringId="DisplayName">Surname</LocalizedString>
        </LocalizedStrings>

      </LocalizedResources>
      <LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccountsignup.de">
        <LocalizedStrings>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="givenName" StringId="DisplayName">Vorname</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="surname" StringId="DisplayName">Nachname</LocalizedString>
        </LocalizedStrings>

      </LocalizedResources>

    </Localization>
```

Comment: DId my answer help solve your issue? If yes, please consider accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the are supposed to be built in, but we have them set up ourselves as well.

This is how you can set you remaining values:

```xml
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" 
            ElementId="email" 
            StringId="DisplayName">E-Mail-Adresse</LocalizedString>

          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" 
            ElementId="newPassword" 
            StringId="DisplayName">Neues Kennwort</LocalizedString>

          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" 
            ElementId="reenterPassword" 
            StringId="DisplayName">Kennwort wiederholen</LocalizedString>


You probably don't need these, but just in case:
          <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="button_continue">Weiter</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="button_cancel">Abbrechen</LocalizedString>
```

As a guideline, you can also look for those claims in the `TrustFrameworkBase` file and by inspecting the fields in your browser using the developer tools. I find this helps me most of the time to find the correct values.

Comment: Thanks, after some more searching is also found this page from the general overview 

[learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/…](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-localization) 

which list the elements. 

Still it is strange that only the buttons are translated automatically.

Comment: Ok thanks everyone. I still believe they could provide those plumbing settings - hence they have it when you follow the user flow way through Azure Portal.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the **Content Definitions 2.0.0**, B2C doesn't automatically translate your claims. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout#self-asserted-page-selfasserted

If you want to automatically translate your claims you need to manually translate them using some

```
  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ContentDefinitions>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountpasswordreset">
        <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="ReplaceAll">
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="bg" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.localaccountpasswordreset.bg" />
          ...
      </ContentDefinition>
    </ContentDefinitions>
    <Localization Enabled="true">
      <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en" MergeBehavior="ReplaceAll">
        <SupportedLanguage>bg</SupportedLanguage>
        ...
      </SupportedLanguages>
      <LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccountpasswordreset.bg">
        <LocalizedCollections />
        <LocalizedStrings>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="signInName" StringId="DisplayName">BG: Text</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="signInName" StringId="UserHelpText">BG: Text</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="signInName" StringId="PatternHelpText">BG: Text</LocalizedString>
        </LocalizedStrings>
      </LocalizedResources>
    ...
    </Localization>
  </BuildingBlocks>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Here you can see the same policy with the parameter `&ui_locales=bg` first using a content definition 1.0.0 (left) and then using a content definition 2.1.4 (right)

[image]